# How to make code compile when Java generic type inference not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, type-inference

I am using Java stream API to combine several maps.

The logic is like this: {1:a,2:b} + {1:b,3:c} = {1:[a,b],2:[b],3:[c]}

I flat the maps to K-V pairs, and using "group by key" to collect the result. The result type is `Map<Key,List<Value>>`.

```
    List<Map<Key, Value>> maps = ....;
    maps.stream().flatMap(s->s.entrySet().stream()).collect(
        groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
            mapping(e -> e.getValue(),  toList())
        )
    );
```

The code about is OK.

Then I want to apply some operations to each value of the result map. For a simple example make [a,b] to "ab". So I added `collectingAndThen` to apply the transformation `x->x` on them.

```
    List<Map<Key, Value>> maps = ....;
    maps.stream().flatMap(s->s.entrySet().stream()).collect(
        groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
            mapping(e -> e.getValue(),  collectingAndThen(toList(),x->x))
        )
    );
```

and the code above won't compile using eclipse JDT saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Value>` to `List<Object>`"

and if i change the simple `x-x` to the "real one" `x->transformValue(x)` more error message appears on `e -> e.getKey()` and `e -> e.getValue()`:

```
The method getKey() is undefined for the type Object
The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object
The method transformValue(List<Value>) in the type 
Sometype is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)
```

How can I work around with this problem? Any ways to tell the compiler that the `<T>` in `toList() -- public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList()` is the class `Value` not `Object`? Thanks.

EDIT:

As Stephan Herrmann said in comment, this is a bug of Eclipse JDT http://bugs.eclipse.org/489976  and will be fixed in 4.6.

Comment: When you say 'not working', are you alleging a compiler bug? If so what section of the JLS is it violating?

Comment: I suggest you specify the generic types in as many places as possible. This could either a) show what is wrong with the code, b) pinpoint where the type inference fails.

Comment: The Eclipse compiler sometimes has trouble with these. Slightly annoying.

Comment: @EJP I am not allenging a compiler bug since I don't have time to read JLS. I think maybe I am not providing enough information to the complier to  infer the type information. I am finding ways to get my code working and I am not sure my code is correct or not.

Comment: @Kayaman Slightly annoying. In IntelliJ my code works.

Comment: So when you say 'not working' what you mean is ' not operating according to my expectations', whatever they may be.

Comment: @Kayaman: Remove the word “slightly”. We are close to the second anniversary of the Java 8 release and Eclipse still doesn’t get it right. Once, Eclipse used to be a Java development tool, but it doesn’t seem to be a high priority anymore.

Comment: It would be worth specifying which version of Eclipse you are using, and trace your issue down to the corresponding Eclipse bug number.

Comment: @Holger I've been using Eclipse since it was still called VisualAge For Java. Nothing that Eclipse does (or doesn't do) surprises me anymore. In fact that's the sort of thing I've come to expect from Eclipse.

Comment: @DidierL, you're right. Since no one else was acting on this I created https://bugs.eclipse.org/489976

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/489976 has been fixed, to appear in milestone 7 towards Eclipse Neon (4.6). Using the next build from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ the workaround will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code compiles without error for me, but I'm using IntelliJ instead of Eclipse.

To explicitly specify the type argument of `toList()`, invoke it with `Collectors.<Value>toList()`.

Comment: I opened IntelliJ and it compiles without error, and when I type ".get(0)." after "x->x" IntelliJ correctly suggested the methods of `Value` class.  It seems there are some differences between Eclipse and IntelliJ in type inference.  I have to  explicitly specify the type argument in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cast to the function consumed by `collectingAndThen`, eg.. `(List<Value> x) x->x`, and make it so:

```
List<Map<Key, Value>> maps = ....;
maps.stream().flatMap(s->s.entrySet().stream()).collect(
    groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
        mapping(e -> e.getValue(),  collectingAndThen(toList(),(List<Value> x) x->x))
    )
);
```

By the time it goes into `collectingAndThen` it infers it should be a function returning a `List<Object>` which does not match with expected `List<Value>`...

---

If you see such a problem a useful practice is to revert from a lambda shorthand to a full function and see if it *does* compile with explicit typing, e.g.:

```
Function<List<Value>, List<Value>> f = new Function<List<Value>, List<Value>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Value> apply(List<Value> x) {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Another tip is that in stream fluent APIs there can be a lot of type inference along the way and some of that can be not what you would expect...

Comment: `(List<Value> x) ->x`  or `Type::transformValue` helped the compiler to inference type argument. Thanks :)